# uikit dynamic grid bug?

Tags: jquery, css, getuikit

I recently decided to start a new project, and since it highly depends on dynamic grid, so I decided to use [uikit](http://getuikit.com). But I cant manage to make it work without errors.

It seems to be a bug in `data-uk-grid-match`.

[Here is sample jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shahab1363/4uu36pma/)

Here is some output examples when I use `data-uk-grid-match` with `data-uk-grid`:
[image: Demo 1]
[image: Demo 2]
[image: Demo 3]
[image: Demo 4]
[image: Demo 5]
[image: Demo 6]

Answer (score 0):

I forked your JSfiddle and it looks pretty good!

Take a look: https://goo.gl/e3njYQ

The only thing I've changed are the **external files**. Check it out.